# return value from function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I asked a similar question earlier but I think I'm closer to the answer now.

I have a function that validates users' email addresses and passwords before they can log in to a profile.

It generates an error message that if the email is not correct; It echoes out " no matching email found".

When I enter correct email and password nothing gets returned. But if I then enter wrong password and wrong email it gives me  "no matching email found". The same thing happens with correct email but wrong password.

I have tried to return with `fetchAll` and `fetchColum` but I still get the same loop when I'm entering correct values.

Any ideas ?

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email AND password =:password";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(":email" => $email, ":password" => $password));
    $results = $query->fetchAll();

    if($results !=FALSE && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
       if($results[0]['password'] == $password){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            return $query->fetchAll($q,0)==1 ? true:false;
        }
    }

    // return false by default
    return false;
}
```

The post isset

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
    if (valid_credientials($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) == false) {
        $errors[] = 'No matching email found.';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
        header("Location: profile.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `fetchAll()` twice, it's useless (and maybe it leads to unexpected behaviors too)

Comment: So refreshing to see someone using `PDO` instead of `mysql*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a default `return false;` statement:

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email AND password =:password";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(array(":email" => $email, ":password" => $password));
    $results = $query->fetchAll();

    if($results !=FALSE && $query->rowCount() > 0) {
       if($results[0]['password'] == $password){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            return $query->fetchAll($q,0)==1 ? true:false;
        }
    }

    // return false by default
    return false;
}
```

Btw, code indention is your friend ;)

However this can be optimized to be more stable:

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email AND password =:password";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    if(!$query) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to prepare the query');
    }

    $ret = $query->execute(array(":email" => $email, ":password" => $password));
    if(!$ret) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to execute the query');
    }

    $results = $query->fetchAll();
    if($results === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to fetch results');
    }

    if(count($results) > 0) {
        // additional password check is not necessary
        return true;
    }

    // return false by default
    return false;
}
```

Comment: well, I tried the return false, but i still loops back to my login form :/

Comment: Then there are other errors. Would need to see the whole solution

Comment: I updated my code, with the isset, I been stuck with this for plenty of hours .garh :)

Comment: @Dymond what do you mean by "loop back"?

Comment: @Uby I wont get any errors, it just reload my login page, The same way if there was wrong email/password but without giving me the " email/password" error

Comment: @Uby Yes. I have a error_reporting(E_ALL); inside the page, but it gives me nothing.

Comment: @Dymond Did you try to `var_dump($errors)`? Check if it's empty or not

Comment: @Uby yes it is actually empty. damn pdo  whats up.?

Comment: @Dymond if it's empty it means your function returned correct values. Looking at your code it should set `$_SESSION` and redirect. Are you sure headers aren't already sent?

Comment: @Uby . I created a pastebin. first time I actually do it. but pdo is giving me the grey hair.

http://pastebin.com/VqMbKEjP

Answer (score 0):

Dunno why you write so much code

```
function valid_credientials($email,$password){
    global $db;

    $q = "SELECT 1 FROM user WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute(func_get_args());
    return $query->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: `fetchColumn()` => Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.  hope OP is not check true by == or ===